# Weird bug when pushing a reactjs app to my github, none of my changes to react will show

Tags: reactjs, macos, github

I created a react app doing `npx create-react-app my-app`, I edited everything and created my app. Everything works fine on localhost. I pushed the app to the github and suddenly when I look at the github it uploaded a boiler plate with only the Ractjs logo and text, none of my files, my code anything. This started happening 2 days ago. I'm not sure if that can be there reason but I updated my macOS same day.

To clarify, imagine I created a Hello World app. It works fine on localhost, but when I push to git I get only the Reactjs logo and the text it comes with.

Here is how I'm pushing to git:

```
git init
git add -A
git remote add origin myaddres
git push -u -f origin master
```

Comment: Could you try and add a specific file, example:
git add readme.md 

Commit and push. Then, verify if the file is in the remote correct?

Comment: seems like I forgot to commit it, it worked now. But I still don't understand how it would send the standard boiler plate to github without any of my files if this was the first push.